# Como selecionar dados do mês e ano anterior?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aplicação-web, select

Estou tentando fazer uma busca a partir de datas no MySql.

Preciso obter a soma total de um valor onde o ano e o mês sejam menores que os informados na variável:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_pag) FROM controle WHERE MONTH(data_paga) < 07 and YEAR(data_paga) <= 2017
```

Mas ele está ignorando meses como: 08/2016, 09/2016, 10/2016, 11/2016 e 12/2016, pelo fato do mês estar condicionado a ser menor que 07 em `MONTH(data_paga) < 07`.

Minha intenção é pegar todos os registros do mês anterior pra trás, entende? Mas a query entende que deve ignorar meses maiores que 7, por isso que 08/2016, 09/2016, 10/2016, 11/2016 e 12/2016, ou mesmo 08/2015, 09/2015, 10/2015, 11/2015 e 12/2015 ficam de fora e assim por diante

O Que pode estar errado?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate         tente data_paga <= subdate(curdate(),inteval 1 month)

Answer (score 1):

tá faltando só um "OR" aí:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_pag) FROM controle 
    WHERE (MONTH(data_paga) < 07 and YEAR(data_paga) <= 2017) or
          (YEAR(data_paga) < YEAR(now()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma outra alternativa que seria utilizar usar o primeiro dia do mês e então obter apenas o que é anterior, por exemplo usando o `MAKEDATE()`:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_pag)
 FROM controle
  WHERE data_paga < MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) - DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) + 1)
```

Uma outra opção seria usar o `LAST_DAY()` dessa forma:

```
SELECT SUM(valor_pag)
 FROM controle
  WHERE data_paga <= LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```