# SELECT Union ALL Desconsidera Argumentos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho Esta query que soma dois resultados em tabelas diferentes.

```
SELECT 
    sum(g) saldo_anterior 
from (
    SELECT 
        SUM(valor_pg) g 
    FROM ctrl_deposito 
    WHERE MONTH(data_pg) < 11 and
    YEAR(data_pg) <= 2016  or
    YEAR(data_pg) < 2016 and
    departamento = "BRADESCO"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        SUM(valor) 
    FROM concessionarias 
    WHERE MONTH(data) < 11 and 
    YEAR(data) <= 2016  or 
    YEAR(data) < 2016 and 
    tipo = "BOLETO" OR 
    tipo = "COPASA" OR 
    tipo = "TELEFONE" OR 
    tipo = "BRADESCO"
) tabela_virtual
```

Entretanto, ela está desconsiderando os parâmetros de departamento no momento da consulta.

Ex.: Tenho nas minas tabelas registros onde departamento = 'CEMIG' e nenhum registro com departamento = 'BRADESCO' e mesmo assim ela está pegando os registros de 'CEMIG' e adicionando a soma.

Nas consultas individuais (sem usar UNIONN ALL), ele considera, mas quando uno os resultados, todos os parâmetros de DEPARTAMENTO E TIPO são dispensados e somado os dados da tabela.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema está sendo esses `OR` dentro da query,

primeiro que não faz nenhum sentido `YEAR(data) <= 2016 or YEAR(data) < 2016`,
apenas `YEAR(data) <= 2016` equivale a isso,
e depois todos os operadores `AND` são processados primeiro que os operadores `OR` fazendo com que retorne possíveis resultados indesejados.

o correto seria assim:

```
SELECT 
    sum(g) saldo_anterior 
from (
    SELECT 
        SUM(valor_pg) g 
    FROM ctrl_deposito 
    WHERE MONTH(data_pg) < 11 and
    YEAR(data_pg) <= 2016 and
    departamento = "BRADESCO"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        SUM(valor) 
    FROM concessionarias 
    WHERE MONTH(data) < 11 and 
    YEAR(data) <= 2016 and 
    (tipo = "BOLETO" OR 
    tipo = "COPASA" OR 
    tipo = "TELEFONE" OR 
    tipo = "BRADESCO")
) tabela_virtual
```

Os operadores `OR` coloquei entre parenteses, para que sejam processados primeiro, antes dos operadores `AND`

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou, entretanto preciso usar o YEAR(data) <= 2016 or YEAR(data) < 2016, caso contrário ele ignora meses maiores que 11 nos anos anteriores, como 12/2014 - 12/2013. Igual nessa minha pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220754/como-selecionar-dados-do-m%C3%AAs-e-ano-anterior?noredirect=1#comment452983_220754

Comment: então tem que fazer assim: `WHERE (MONTH(data_pg) < 11 and YEAR(data_pg) <= 2016 OR  YEAR(data_pg) < 2016) AND...`

Comment: Sim. Obrigado pela sua ajuda. Funcionou perfeitamente.